# Convert bunch of timestamps into "Number of hits" per day info

Tags: php, statistics, timestamp

Lets say all I have is a bunch of timestamps that represent the time of the click like this:

1298888707, 1298891521, 1298907490, 1298999649, 1299002856, 1299003880, 1299055121, 1299059489, 1299059576, 1299062919, 1299068122, 1299079105, 1299080116, 1299081230, 1299086709, 1299144900, 1299149635, 1299167764, 1299169121, 1299169661, 1299172766, 1299173590, 1299196306, 1299210407, 1299226740, 1299227733, 1299228702, 1299229643, 1299230315, 1299231007, 1299232040, 1299239872, 1299243267, 1299243584, 1299244186, 1299244830, 1299246051, 1299246365, 1299246526, 1299247302, 1299247540, 1299247637

What is the easiest and fastest way to convert those in a "click by day" stats array?
End result would be a php array with something like this:

```
$clicks = array(4, 25, 0, 34, 23);
```

Where 4 would be the number of clicks on day 0, 25 the number of clicks on day 1, 0 the number of clicks on day 2, etc...

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Convert to dates, and group by day?

Comment: Do you have these timestamps in a database or only in an array?

Comment: In a database here's the typical request : SELECT hit_date FROM stats_hits WHERE filename LIKE "%nameoffile%" order by hit_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's OK to have the array keyed by dates, then you could do something like this:

```
<?php

$hits = array();

foreach ($array_of_timestamps as $timestamp)
{
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
    if (!isset($hits[$currentDate]))
    {
        $hits[$currentDate] = 0;
    }

    $hits[$currentDate]++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nils, your script works fine, the only issue is that would need it to also add keys for the dates that don't have any clicks.
##
Instead of having:
[2011-04-06] => 1 [2011-04-08] => 1 
##
It would be: [2011-04-06] => 1 [2011-04-07] => 0 [2011-04-08] => 1

Comment: @Phil What are you, his boss?

Comment: @bzlm Why? did that sound rude? If it did I apologize, wasn't my intention. The current script won't interact with my page like it would need, I was just asking for help tweaking it..

Comment: @Phil It didn't sound rude. It did sound, though, as if you're using SO to get people like Nils to write all your code for you, rather than for Q&A regarding programming. Surely you could add that last piece of "2011-04-07 => 0" logic yourself? :)

Comment: @bzlm hmmm, I see what you mean. But I don't really see an easy way of doing this. The only way I can think of is to do another loop after generating the whole array that would check if there are days missing, I was wondering if someone had an idea to integrate it directly in the main loop.

Comment: @Phil You could always interpret `undefined` as 0 on the consuming side. Then [2011-04-07] would be 0.

Comment: @Phil As @blzm says, it would simply be a case of checking at the consuming end for an unset key.